# res.sendFile is being aborted, sending me to localhost:XXXX/?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

I have a route set up that is being accessed, as I know from the console.logs. However, The res.sendFile at the end is not taking it to the correct place. It sends me to localhost:XXXX/?.

This is the route:

```
router.get('/bidder', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('GET /bidder')
  console.log(req.session.user_id)
  
  try {
    const userData = await User.findByPk(req.session.user_id, {
      attributes: { exclude: ['password'] },
      include: [
        { 
          model: Project,
          attributes: ['project_name'],
          through: Bid,
          as: 'project_users'
        }
      ],
    });

    console.log(path.join(__dirname, '/../public', '/bidder.html'))
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../public', '/bidder.html',), function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

And this is the route that gets me to the /bidder route above:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  console.log('POST /login');
  try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: req.body.email } });

      if (!user) {
          res
              .status(400)
              .json({ message: 'Incorrect email or password, please try again.' });
          return;
      }

      const validPassword = await user.checkPassword(req.body.password);

      if (!validPassword) {
          res
              .status(400)
              .json({ message: 'Incorrect email or password, please try again.' });
          return;
      }

      req.session.save(() => {
        console.log(user);
        console.log(user.id);
        console.log(user.is_poster);
        
        req.session.user_id = user.id;
        req.session.is_poster = user.is_poster;
        req.session.logged_in = true;
        
        console.log(req.session.logged_in)
        
        if (req.session.is_poster == false) {
          console.log('---------------------------')
          console.log(req.session.is_poster)
          console.log(path.join(__dirname, '/../public/bidder.html'))
          
          res.redirect('/bidder')
        } else if (req.session.is_poster == true) {
          console.log('---------------------------')
          console.log(req.session.is_poster)
          console.log(path.join(__dirname, '/../public/poster.html'))
          
          res.redirect('/poster')
        } else {
          console.log('not logged in')
          
          res.redirect('/')
        }
      });

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(404).end();
  }
});
```

The error that it is logging is:

```
Error: Request aborted
    at onaborted (C:\Users\camer\Desktop\homework\project-bid-board\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1025:15)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\camer\Desktop\homework\project-bid-board\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1067:9)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21) {
  code: 'ECONNABORTED'
}
```

If I just type localhost:XXXX/bidder into the browser, it sends me to the correct html page, as it should.

**EDIT**
This is the JS associated with submitting the data for login:

```
$('#login-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var email = $('#login-email').val()
    var password = $('#login-password').val()

    loginUser(email, password)
})

const loginUser = async (email, password) => {
    const response = await fetch (`/api/user/login`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })

    console.log(response.statusText)
}
```

And this is the form it is handling:

```
                  <form>
                    <div>
                        <label for="username">E-mail / Username:</label>
                        <input class="text-input" id="login-email" type="text" placeholder="me@example.com" />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        <input class="text-input" type="text" id="login-password" placeholder="password"></input>
                    </div>
                    <section>
                        <button class="btn-lg btn-block" id="login-button">Login</button>
                        <div class="text-center" id="signupSuccessMsg"></div>
                    </section>
                </form>
```

Comment: Are you sending the `/login` route from an Ajax call in your Javascript?  I ask because Ajax calls do NOT follow redirects by default.  They do not change what displays in the browser unless you write your own Javascript to do that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am not.

Comment: Where is the `/login` route being triggered then?  By what?

Comment: Is it possible that `req.session.save()` has an error which you do not have an error handler for?

Comment: What are the logs from the `/login` route before you get the error?

Comment: @jfriend00 Okay so the reason it was auto directing me to localhost:XXXX/? was because I didnt not put preventDefault on the login button. Now it goes through the routes smoothly, however it  stops at `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../public', '/bidder.html',), function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })` without logging any error and does not redirect the page to the bidder.html

Comment: Look in the browser debug console at the network tab and see EXACTLY what the browser is receiving back from the server after the POST.  That will usually shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: Wait, but if you're doing `preventDefault`, then you must be using Javascript in this from.  Please show us the whole form and the Javascript that executes as part of the form.  That's probably where the issue is.

Comment: @jfriend00 I made an edit to the post to add the form and the associated JS. The data from the form, once you press the signin button, does post to the login route as it should. Thank you for helping by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are posting the `/login` with `fetch()` in your Javascript.  `fetch()` by itself does NOT change ANYTHING in the browser window - even if the response is a redirect.

Instead, `fetch()` makes an http request to your server and gets the response and delivers that to your Javascript. It is entirely up to your Javascript to decide what to do with that response.  If you want to follow a redirect, then you have to write your Javascript to look for a 3xx response status from the `fetch()` call, get the `location` header and then set `window.location` to that new URL.  That will then cause the browser to go to that new page.

---

Since your Javascript that's posting the login form doesn't seem to be doing anything special, you could just remove your Javascript and let the browser post the form on its own and make sure your server was programmed to accept the way the form would be encoded if posted directly by the browser.  Then, the browser WOULD follow the redirect response automatically or would display any content that the post returned.

Comment: Adding `window.location = response.url` after the fetch in the JS solved the issue. Thank you for the help.